# Where do Django model fields reside?

Tags: python, django

I've looked into the source code for some django model fields, in this case [`DateTimeField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/_modules/django/db/models/fields/#DateTimeField). In the tutorial for Django, we are taught to create a `DateTimeField` like this:

```
from django.db import models

field = models.DateTimeField()
```

But looking in the source code, the file where `DateTimeField` is defined is `django/db/models/fields`. So, intuitively, if I were to import the field, I would write `from django.db.models.fields import DateTimeField`.

Do you see the difference? In the tutorial, they import it from `django/db/models`, while it looks like from the location of the source code that it actually resides in `django/db/models/fields`. Why doesn't the tutorial way of importing `DateTimeField` crash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fields are imported in `django/db/models/__init__.py`

Take a look at [the source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/__init__.py#L12...L15).

Possibly relevant: [What is **init**.py for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for)